# How to boost black in image (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a photo copied image, how do I get it so the blacks are darker?

Please help.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Run a threshold adjustment on the image, anyway this is not apparent form your question. If i hadn't read your other question i would have been at a  loss as to what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually make this adjustment by tweaking the image's `Levels`, rather than a `Threshold` adjustment.

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Drag the black (left) slider, until you're satisfied with the result
- Click OK

[image]

This was done with Levels

[image]

This with Threshold

[image]

As you can see, Threshold will cause your image to lose a lot of detail